# Need a script to delete all temp files beginning with ~$

Tags: script, temporary-files

A recent scan on our file server for temp files with **~$** appended to the start of the name produced nearly 1,000 results.

These files' "Last Modified" dates go back to 2003 (so they are generally all redundant now and can be safely deleted).

I need a script which will identify and delete any files starting with "~$", which I could then schedule to run once a week on the server to purge these temp files automatically on a frequent basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a specific directory this would delete all files with names beginning with ~$ recursively:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name '~$*' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

To limit it with that specific directory only and not with under its subdirectories use maxdepth:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '~$*' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Change the integral argument to `-maxdepth` depending on the intended level of directories to search files into.

Another simpler approach is to use globs but not really a good idea since it would try to touch directories that matches the pattern. It's still won't delete them but you'd have to bother with the error message. You could use `-f` option or send error output to `/dev/null` but it's already dirty for a method:

```
rm '/path/to/directory/~$'*
```

Comment: It would be somewhat more efficient to use `+` -- which means that `{}` expands into a list of files (`find` is smart enough to make sure it stays below the shell's limit) -- rather than `\;`, which means that `{}` expands to a single file. As it stands you are running `rm` once for every file `find` finds, when you probably only need to use it once. Depending on your version of `find` you can also just use the `-delete` option and avoid calling an external command altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. What would the practical advantage of using "+" be vs. using "\;"? And what would the entire script look like? Should I just substitute "\;" for "+"?